join two log tables to get one table with events from two
I'm trying to join two log tables with clickhouse to get one table with all events and ordered by event_date.
The first table



aws_id
zip
is_mail_approved
created_at
updated_at




54
0
0
2021-06-18 21:05:11
2023-08-08 16:18:29


54
317317
1
2021-06-18 21:05:11
2023-08-09 14:14:15


54
317317
1
2021-06-18 21:05:11
2023-09-19 09:30:36



the second table



aws_id
aws_exporter_id
updated_at




54
5
2023-08-08 16:21:41


54
501
2023-09-19 09:37:42



And i need this result table



aws_id
zip
is_mail_approved
created_at
aws_exporter_id
updated_at




54
0
0
2021-06-18 21:05:11
0
2023-08-08 16:18:29


54
0
0
2021-06-18 21:05:11
5
2023-08-08 16:21:41


54
317317
0
2021-06-18 21:05:11
5
2023-08-09 14:14:15


54
317317
1
2021-06-18 21:05:11
5
2023-09-19 09:30:36


54
317317
1
2021-06-18 21:05:11
501
2023-09-19 09:37:42



I tried using asof join with <= and >= but the result is not correct

Does this answer your question? Join tables in ClickHouse without equal expressions

This should meet your need:
SELECT *
FROM first_table f
JOIN second_table s ON ( f.aws_id = s.aws_id );

I am not sure why you were using <= or >=.

You can use this:
SELECT *
FROM first_table
INNER JOIN second_table
ON ( f.aws_id.aws_id = second_table.aws_id )
ORDER BY updated_at, created_at

I don't know why you used <= or >=, but if you want to order, you should use ORDER BY [what you want] . My query firs order by update_at, if there were equal order by creat_at.
